# Can't execute boot2docker command on TeamCity command line build step

Tags: windows, docker, teamcity, boot2docker

I am trying to add docker commands on TeamCity build steps using the normal command line option. I have Windows environment so I have to use boot2docker.

I can execute the command like:
`"C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows\boot2docker.exe" ssh docker images` on Windows command line. It will return a list of my docker images.

However, I'm not able to run the same command on TeamCity using the Command Line runner type. I always get the error message `error in run: VM "boot2docker-vm" is not running.`
[image]

[image]

Anyone get ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear: `boot2docker-vm is not running`

Login on your server and run `boot2docker up` on its command line. That will start the boot2docker VM. Then try again.